# The cat became his prize

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> Had no choice but to leave his ground 
>   The foe took him by surprise 
>   With his food and shelter lost to the beast 
>   The cat became his prize

What is the word referred here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm fairly certain the answer is

> catastrophe

---

Had no choice but to leave his ground

> disasters often force people to evacuate..

The foe took him by surprise

> providing little to no warning..

With his food and shelter lost to the beast

> and take away the most basic of needs.

The cat became his prize

> one could argue that this pun is a cat as trophy :P

Comment: Well your last-line pun certainly seems to fit better than my own idea - I've been trying to fit the other lines with rot13(zrqnyyvba - zrqny... yvba...) - but with no luck!

Comment: That's cool! But yeah, I guess the other lines might be tougher to make sense of with that.